# List file names, not including two strings using grep

Tags: string, bash, grep

I have a folder, where I have bunch of WSDLs. I want to find out which WSDLs do not include string 'binding style="document"' 'binding style="rpc"'.
I have tried following grep command but it aint working, I guess because it check with OR not with AND.

```
grep -Ev 'binding style=\"rpc\"|binding style=\"document\"' -l folder/* | cut -f2 -d'/'
```

Comment: `grep "a|b"` is an OR. To get an AND, do `grep a | grep b`.

Comment: Is it possible to do it by specifing the folder?

Comment: `grep -v a folder/* | grep -lv b` should make it.

Comment: The logic about AND is wrong. If you're going to exclude lines then then the OR solution is already correct since `!(A|B)` == `(!A && !B)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `awk` instead of `grep` as it lets you combine regex matches with logical operators:

To print lines that have both matches:

```
$ awk '$0~s1 && $0~s2' s1='binding style="rpc"' s2='binding style="document"'
```

To print lines that have at least one match:

```
$ awk '$0~s1 || $0~s2' s1='binding style="rpc"' s2='binding style="document"'
```

To print lines that have neither matches

```
$ awk '!($0~s1 || $0~s2)' s1='binding style="rpc"' s2='binding style="document"'
```

---

To print just the filenames you would do the following with `GNU awk` for files containing both matches on a single line:

```
$ awk '$0~s1 && $0~s2{print FILENAME;nextfile}'
```

Files containing at least one match:

```
$ awk '$0~s1 || $0~s2{print FILENAME;nextfile}'
```

Files containing both matches across any lines:

```
$ awk '$0~s1{f1=1} $0~s2{f2=1}ENDFILE{if (f1&&f2) print FILENAME;f1=f2=0}'
```

Files containing no matches:

```
$ awk '$0~s1{f1=1} $0~s2{f2=1}ENDFILE{if (!(f1||f2)) print FILENAME;f1=f2=0}'
```

You still need to add the definitions of `s1` and `s2` I left them off only to keep the lines short for readability. The reason I choose to define `s1` and `s2` after the script is because the strings contains double quotes and doing it this way avoiding any nasty escaping. If you had matches without quotes you could simple do:

```
$ awk '/foo/ && /bar/{print FILENAME;nextfile}' folder/* | basename
```

For the strings `foo` and `bar` ect...

Comment: How can I specify the folder?

Comment: The same way you was with `grep` by using shell globings to pass in all the files `awk '$0~s1 && $0~s2' s1='binding style="rpc"' s2='binding style="document"' folder/*`. Side tip: the command `basename` strips the leading directories from a file so you can replace `cut -f2 -d'/'` with `basename`.

Comment: So I tried it out, seems to work but it prints out the matching files:( But I want names. Where am I supposed to attach the basename?

Comment: I think you meant "it prints out the matching **lines** not filenames" I have added how you would print just filenames for the 4 cases. `basename` is a command just like `cut` so you will pipe the result of the `awk` command to `basename` just like you are doing with `grep` and `cut` currently. You could easily add the functional of removing the leading directories in the `awk` script itself but that's probably best left for later on.

Answer (score 1):

When using single quotes, you don't have to quote `"`:

```
grep -vE 'binding style="rp"|binding style="document"' -l folder/* | cut -f2 -d'/'
```

To have files not containing the patterns:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; ++i) {
        m = 0
        file = ARGV[i]
        while ((getline line < file) > 0) {
            if (line ~ /binding style="rp"|binding style="document"/) {
                m = 1
                break
            }
        }
        close(file)
        if (m == 0) {
            print file
        }
    }
    exit
}' folder/* | cut -f2 -d'/'
```

One-line command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<ARGC;++i){m=0;file=ARGV[i];while((getline line<file)>0){if(line ~ /binding style="rp"|binding style="document"/){m=1;break}}close(file);if(m==0){print file}}exit}' folder/* | cut -f2 -d'/'
```

To just see the filename:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; ++i) {
        m = 0
        file = ARGV[i]
        while ((getline line < file) > 0) {
            if (line ~ /binding style="rp"|binding style="document"/) {
                m = 1
                break
            }
        }
        close(file)
        if (m == 0) {
            sub(/.*\//, "", file)
            print file
        }
    }
    exit
}' folder/*
```

You no longer have to use cut.

One-line command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<ARGC;++i){m=0;file=ARGV[i];while((getline line<file)>0){if(line ~ /binding style="rp"|binding style="document"/){m=1;break}}close(file);if(m==0){sub(/.*\//,"",file);print file}}exit}' folder/*
```

Comment: @Marko Aren't you planning to exclude those lines?

Comment: I think this solution doesn't work if each WSDL file has any line with data different from those two string. Because `-v` would match it and `-l` would print the file name. It would be easier an approach with `-L` and without `-v`.

Comment: `-v` = `NOT`. and `binding style="rp"|binding style="document"` = `NOT binding style="rp" AND NOT binding style="document"`

Comment: @Birei Depends if there indeed some lines like that in those files.

Comment: @Marko What is the pattern to recognize a valid line?

Comment: I need the name of the files that don't have binding style="rpc" and also binding style="document". Atm this grep gives names of files with  OR, which means it basically shows me all the files including rpc and document styled WSDLs

Answer (score 1):

This prints the filenames of all the files that do not contain the strings `binding style="rp"` or `binding style="document"`

```
perl -le 'for $f (@ARGV) { $p=0;open($fh,$f); while(<$fh>) { $p++ if (/binding style="rp"|binding style="document"/); } print $f unless $p;}' *
```

I assume you want the filenames

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 folder/*|perl -lne 'print unless(/binding style=\"(rpc|document)\"/)' |cut -f2 -d'/'
```

Comment: This also seems to work with OR, but I need to find files that doesnt include both of the strings.